# The products of powers of Hermitian operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator

Let's say I have two operators, $\hat{x}^k$ and $\hat{p}_x^l$, where $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}_x$ are the ordinary position and momentum operators. It seems fairly straight forward to show that $\hat{x}^k$ and $\hat{p}_x^l$ are Hermitian. And the product of two Hermitian operators is Hermitian if they commute. However, it seems like something funny happens with $\hat{x}^k$ and $\hat{p}_x^l$, when I try and work out the commutator. I end up with:

$$
[\hat{x}^k,\hat{p}_x^l] = -\left( \frac{\hbar}{i} \right)^l\frac{\partial^l}{\partial x^l}x^k
$$

If $l=k=1$, then this is just the plain old-fashioned commutator for position and moment. No problems. However, because of the integer powers:

$$
-\left( \frac{\hbar}{i} \right)^l\frac{\partial^l}{\partial x^l}x^k=-\left( \frac{\hbar}{i} \right)^l\frac{\partial^{l-1}}{\partial x^{l-1}}kx^{k-1} = -\left( \frac{\hbar}{i} \right)^l\frac{\partial^{l-2}}{\partial x^{l-2}}(k-1)kx^{k-2}
$$

etc.

So this is the first step that I'm a little unsure of. So my first question is: is the above correct?

Now if $k>l$, then I get:

$$
[\hat{x}^k,\hat{p}_x^l] =-\left( \frac{\hbar}{i} \right)^lk(k-1)(k-2)...(k-l)x^{k-l}
$$
so clearly the two operators do not commute. If $l=k$:

$$
[\hat{x}^k,\hat{p}_x^l] =-\left( \frac{\hbar}{i} \right)^lk!
$$
And again, they don't commute. However, if I let $l>k$, then:

$$
\begin{align}
[\hat{x}^k,\hat{p}_x^l] &= 
-\left( \frac{\hbar}{i} \right)^{l-k}\frac{\partial^{l-k}}{\partial x^{l-k}}x^k!x^0\\
\\
 &=-\left( \frac{\hbar}{i} \right)^{l-k}\frac{\partial^{l-k-1}}{\partial x^{l-k-1}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}k!\\ \\
&=0
\end{align}
$$

So now they commute and $\hat{x}^k\hat{p}_x^l$ is Hermitian! What's happened here? Have I made some trivial error somewhere?

Comment: The first equation (v1) is incorrect.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you. Doing it again, I can see that it should be quite different, as I have only applied the product rule once, when it should be applied $l$ times. However, my situation is now worse, because I end up with a long expression that I can't simplify.